# Is there way to choose between Newtonsoft.json and System.Text.Json in Actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I use ASP.NET Core 5, I don't want to migrate from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`, but in some cases, I want to use `System.Text.Json` to increase performance in controller actions.

For example, in ActionA, I want to use default behavior of `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer and in ActionB, I want to change behaviour to `System.Text.Json` serializer.

Comment: Bad idea. .NET core was optimised not to use newtonsoft anymore for performance reasons. Better to use the new way of working immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no build-in way to specific the Jsonconvert for specific controller.

If you want to modify the generated json result jsonconvert, I suggest you could try to use this way.

I suggest you could try to use actionfilter to achieve your requirement.

By using actionfilter, you could modift the input formatter to use other jsonconvert to convert the data.

```
public class CaseActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IgnoreNullValues = true
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CaseAction]
    public ActionResult Index([FromForm]Member member) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

If you want to set the convert for the model binder, the only way is create a cusotmer modle binder and modify the json formatter according to each model type. There is no way to achieve it according to asp.net core has modified the iresoucefilter to not support change is formater.

Comment: I believe that this misses handling for the case the action returning a `JsonResult`.